# Google Drive - how to move a specific file (.pdf) from a specific folder to another

Tags: javascript

My english is a colander and my programming skills in Javascript the same. I have in a specific folder of Google Drive several PDF files (about 10). Once a day, near midnight, I have to move these files separately (one for one) in specific Google Drive folders.
Actually I make this activity by hand, so I tried to automate it with a simple script.

I'm able to point to the specific folder, but NOT to the specific file.
In the samples I found around in Internet all files contained in a folder are moved to another folder, so the filesIterator technique are used.
But I don't need to iterate, I need to point the specific file and move it to anther folder.

Here my five (confused) program lines:

```
function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {

var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B42Jhhzp_5X7QUlMdE9SZS0wMms');  
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B42Jhhzp_5X7TFZBMXpfeWpZNFk');

var file = getFilesByName('caa20170829.pdf');

// var files = source_folder.getFiles();
// Logger.log(file.getAs(MimeType.HTML).getDataAsString());

dest_folder.addFile(file);
source_folder.removeFile(file);
}
```

The error message I'm getting:

> ReferenceError: "getFilesByName" not defined. (line 6, file "move")

Any help would be appreciated!

---

As suggested from Max Deepfield (thanks, Max), I edited the line 6 as follows

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('caa20170829.pdf');
```

and the error message changed to

> Impossible to find the method addFile(FileIterator). (line 11, file "move")

Now i edited the 11. line as follows

```
DriveApp.dest_folder.addFile(file);
```

and the error message changes another time...

> TypeError: Impossible to call the method "addFile" of undefined. (line 11, file "move")

Thanks to Hassan too, i am studying the examples he suggested.
But if someone would give further help...   I thank in advance.

Comment: are you sure it is not `DriveApp.getFilesByName` ?

Comment: Take a look at this https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder

Comment: Hassan, many thanks for your tip.

I edited as from you suggested. In fact, now sounds the error message as follows: Impossible to find the method addFile(FileIterator). (line 11, file "move")

Comment: Sorry, the suggestion came from Max Deepfield, many thanks, Max. 
Now i edited the 11. line as follows "DriveApp.dest_folder.addFile(file);"  and the erre message is changed too...  "TypeError: Impossible to call the method "addFile" of undefined. (line 11, file "move")"

Comment: Edit your question and post the new code and the new problem, don't use the comments for it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the DriveApp Api doesn't have any methods to return single `File`. So you have to pass by the `FileIterator`. 
First you don't have to put parameters in `function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder)`, `source_folder` and `dest_folder` are defined inside the function. But I think you did this mistake du to the code you find on internet :) 
Moreover, there is some wrong advice here: when you call `DriveApp.getFolderById()`, the API will return you a `Folder`. So you don't need to call `DriveApp` on this var anymore (for example `DriveApp.dest_folder.addFile(file);` is a bad call because the method `addFile()` is for `Folder` type, and `dest_folder` is already a `Folder`. 
So you could try this, it works for me:

```
source_folder= DriveApp.getFolderById('YourFolderID1')
  dest_folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('YourFolderID2')

  var files = source_folder.getFilesByName("YourFileName").next();
  dest_folder.addFile(files);
  source_folder.removeFile(files);
```

I hope it helped you :)

Comment: Hi Baptistee, i thank you mery much for your help.
Simply GALACTIC!!
It worked at the first time, very very good!!
Many thanks again, and best regards from Italy.
Aldo